# Windows 7 random crashes

Tags: windows-7, ssd, crash, bsod

I have a Windows 7 computer with this hardware:

- Asus P8P67 PRO
- Intel i7 2600k
- 8GB RAM
- AMD Radeon HD 6970
- 2TB HDD (used for storing data)
- 128GB SSD OCZ Vertex III (used for the OS)

The PC works fine but Windows crashes after some time (sometimes after an hour, sometimes after 4 hours, etc). I can see it because when I open an application, it hangs and doesn't open, and if I click on the start button, explorer crashes. After that, if I wait it goes to blue screen and re-crashes (never reboots): I have to shutdown and restart the PC.

Does anyone else have this kind of problem? I can't understand what it is and why it happens. I thought it could be that the space left on the SSD was too small but it has 17GB free.

Blue Screen screenshot:

[image]

After reboot screen (error code is `0xc000000e`):

[image]

---

If it can help, here it is the SMART tool output (OCZ Smart Tool):

```
SMART Data

Model Number:   OCZ-VERTEX3                             
Serial Number:  OCZ-9ZT05SBV48Z463R8
WWN:        5e83a97f9cd3c7c7

 ID ATTRIBUTE                           STATUS  VALUE   WORST   THRESHOLD   TYPE    UPDATED RAW
  1 Raw Read Error Rate                 0x000f  094 094 050 Pre-fail    Always      153/30264473
  5 Retired Block Count                 0x0033  100 100 003 Pre-fail    Always      0
  9 Power-On Hours                      0x0032  094 094 000 Old age     Always      5647h+41m+16.559s
 12 Device Power Cycle Count            0x0032  099 099 000 Old age     Always      1938
171 Program Fail Count                  0x0032  000 000 000 Old age     Always      0
172 Erase Fail Count                    0x0032  000 000 000 Old age     Always      1
174 Unexpected Power Loss               0x0030  000 000 000 Old age     Offline     862
177 Wear Range Delta                    0x0000  000 000 000 Old age     Offline     3
181 Program Fail Count                  0x0032  000 000 000 Old age     Always      0
182 Erase Fail Count                    0x0032  000 000 000 Old age     Always      1
187 Reported Uncorrectable              0x0032  100 100 000 Old age     Always      0
194 Temperature Celsius                 0x0022  128 129 000 Old age     Always      128 (Min/Max 127/129)
195 ECC On-the-Fly Error Count          0x001c  120 120 000 Old age     Offline     153/30264473
196 Reallocation Event Count            0x0033  097 097 003 Pre-fail    Always      4294967295
201 Uncorrectable Soft Read Error Rate  0x001c  120 120 000 Old age     Offline     153/30264473
204 Soft ECC Correction Rate            0x001c  120 120 000 Old age     Offline     153/30264473
230 Life Curve Status                   0x0013  100 100 000 Pre-fail    Always      94987496718436
231 SSD Life Left                       0x0013  100 100 010 Pre-fail    Always      0
241 Lifetime Writes from Host           0x0032  000 000 000 Old age     Always      5111
242 Lifetime Reads to Host              0x0032  000 000 000 Old age     Always      7200
```

Note: MemTest shown no errors on my RAM.

---

**UPDATE**

HWMonitor screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Uhm, might be completely wrong here, but 128 °C sounds a "bit" too hot to me? This is an SSD?

Comment: @Mario Yes, it's an OCZ Vertex III

Comment: Can you try some other tool (like HW Monitor) and see what temperature it reports? That 128 is either total off (value reported/interpreted wrong) or indeed the culprit. If the temperature is fine (like 20-40 °C), keep an eye on it while running the PC for a bit.

Comment: @Mario check the update

Comment: A number like that for my overclocked asus setup would have indicated that I pushed the memory too hard. it would also do the similar action of working for quite some time then failing with bluescreen.  Can you test by setting the divisor for the memory lower, increase the memory voltage a bit or reduce the timings some ,or temprarily supercooling it.  Also you could do a memtest86 (not windoze) overnight.

Comment: @Psycogeek I have no overclock and I will not do any overclock. And as I wrote, I already did a memtest86 and reported no errors.

Comment: I was not trying to say you overclocked.  I read what you wrote, it does not indicate that you tested for 12 hours?  Dont get me wrong i would not test for 12 hours either :-)   but people have and discovered things.  What i was asking you to test would be to lower the memory a bit and see if it still happens.  I also think your 840 change might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

0xF4 means a critical process has been terminated. It can be either software or hardware and if you upload your DMP file to Skydrive or another file sharing service we can tell you which.

In the interim I would run a system file check (to check for software) and a CHKDSK to check the HD

Please run a system file check (SFC)

All instructions are in our Wiki article below...
Should you have any questions please ask us.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-system/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93

Comment: Both CHKDSK and SFC show no error. Where can I find the DMP file? Anyway, I don't think there is some dump file on my machine. The problem seems to be related to the SSD: if the SSD crashes and it can't be read/written to, then no dump files can be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem is definitely the SSD overheating due to whatever reason (even if it's just due to a faulty sensor it might shut off to prevent damage despite there being no real reason to do so).

128 °C is definitely far too hot. The temperature should be somewhere around 30-40 °C based on air flow etc.

If possible, remove it from the case and place it on a surface that's able to withstand that temperature easily (like a pan) and see whether it's still getting that hot (don't touch it, use some thermometer).

Comment: I just read that it might be a bug of the OCZ firmware/sensors. On some forum they say that after applying the fix they get a 30°/40° stable temperature. The fact is that the link to the fix went down, I'm searching. Thank you!

Comment: @Harlandraka Just look for updated firmware would be my first bet, but if you do so, update it right after booting to avoid any stops while flashing, which might render the drive inaccessible. Backup your data just in case!

Comment: I will definitely do so. I'll keep you up to date, right now I'm searching for this fix. I'll install it and wait for another blue screen :)

Comment: Ok Mario: _Assuming your SSD is an OCZ Agility 3 or Vertex 3, the temps reported are fake_ ***(there's no sensor on the SSD)***. _The fix from OCZ simply changes the report value and locks it at 30C._ I'm trying to find the fix, if it doesn't work, I'll change the SSD (maybe with a Samsung 840, it never gave me problems) and never buy OCZ hardware again

Comment: That sounds odd, why would someone use such absurd fake value? Sure, it makes it easy to tell that it's fake, but at the same time that's no real solution. Maybe try their firmware tool? http://ocz.com/consumer/download/firmware

Comment: I updated the firmware and nothing changed, Temperature is always locked at 180°C. What else should I try? (Apart from throwing my ssd out of the window)